# how to bind input key to itemscontrol in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, key-bindings, inputbinding

I have an items control which has items on a canvas, when I press delete I want to delete an item from the canvas:

```
<ItemsControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}" Key="Delete"/>
</ItemsControl.InputBindings>
```

However, the method in DeleteItemCommand is never called.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do other commands work as you've set them up?  There are several different command binding conventions, just wondering if you could complete your code example showing how the commands are set up and whether that XAML shares a DataContext that can see that command binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` (or possibly something within) needs to be [`Focusable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) to receive keyboard input.

Comment: Setting Focusable="True" on my ItemsControl items enables them to be deleted when focused, thank you, however the only way to focus them is by tabbing to them, or by a bit of a hack - finding the stackpanel on Mouse_Down capture on the canvas items. Is there a way to focus the items when they are added to the canvas? (object is added to the ItemSource collection through mouse click on the canvas)

Comment: You saved me with this answer!